# golang http server send r.URL.Path over socket

Tags: go

I have a http server, and I want to send the r.URL.Path text to a client using a socket

I get a error:  undefined: conn in conn.Write
This is becauase conn is defined in another function

What I have tried:

```
package main

import (
    "net"
    "io"
    "net/http"
)


ln, _ := net.Listen("tcp", ":8081")
conn, _ := ln.Accept()

func hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    io.WriteString(w, "Hello world!")
    conn.Write([]byte(r.URL.Path + "\n")) //Here I'm attemping to send it
}

func main() {


    http.HandleFunc("/", hello)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: undefined: conn in conn.Write @grooveplex

Comment: The function `hello` cannot refer to the local variable `conn` in `main`.  Perhaps you want a package-level variable.

Comment: Show what you tried.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I have update my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is actually in the way you try to declare variables.
If you want your conn to be on global scope, use `var`

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "net"
)


var ln, _ = net.Listen("tcp", ":8081")
var conn, _ = ln.Accept()

func hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    io.WriteString(w, "Hello world!")
    conn.Write([]byte(r.URL.Path + "\n")) //Here I'm attemping to send it
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", hello)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}
```

Comment: for some reason io.WriteString(w, "Hello World") give me this error: panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x20 pc=0x23323 @Alexey Soshin

Comment: @D.Jow You got the error because there is no client connected to server through port `8081`.